# How to investigate the calling convention of PE binary file in windows?

Tags: calling-convention, portable-executable

Is there a tool to show whether the calling convention is _cdecl or _stdcall or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling conventions are per function - not PE file.

Library functions. at least the ones provided by MS, are all `_stdcall`. Everything else is spread across other calling conventions, most of them being `_cdecl`.

You can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

The short version:

- `cdecl` functions don't clear it's argument from the stack, allowing variable sized arguments. Good example is `printf()` which can a different number of arguments.
- `stdcall` functions clears arguments from the stack themselves. Hence variable sized arguments isn't possible.

Edit: added example

Example for `cdecl` from [the link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions):

```
push c
push b
push a
call function_name
add esp, 12 ;Stack clearing, 3 arguments take 12 bytes of space (on 32bit)
```

So after `function_name` returns, the caller clears the arguments off the stack.

Comment: How to judge which convention is used by disassembly?